# Не возвращаются данные в Ajax запросе по Ip адресу

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cgi, request

Имеется сервер и его ip адрес. На сервере расположен файл(cgi), к которому идет обращение извне и он соответственно отдает json в зависимости от запроса.
Обращаясь напрямую по ip адресу из строки браузера все данные отображаются корректно, но когда идет обращение из скрипта:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://<ip-address>/cgi-bin/api1.0/Tables?ip=localhost&port=9858&param=m',
 //   data: myData,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function (data, status, errorThrown) {
        alert(status + errorThrown);
    }
    });
    });
```

То выкидывает error (до сервера запрос точно доходит), хотя обращение к другим серверам, например, по доменному имени с параметрами идет корректно и корректно отображаются данные. В чем можем заключаться проблема?

Comment: Откройте в браузере консоль ошибок и посмотрите ошибки js. Может браузер считает эти запросы кросс доменными и срабатывает запрет из-за политики безопасности.

Comment: пишет, что connection - close, это возможно как либо избежать?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно взглянуть на информацию о [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) и/или о [JSONP](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-jsonp).
Обе эти технологии позволяют получить данные с другого домена.